# Direction of the spiral trajectories for coupled differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at the coupled system $x'=ax+by,$ $y'=cx+dy$ with non-real eigenvalues.

Do I know it correctly that the trajectories are clockwise if $b-c$ is positive and anticlockwise if $b-c$ is negative? I am quoting this claim from http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/differential_equations/second_order/qualitative_methods_1.html

Can you also please point me to an online resource where I can find the proof of the condition?

Comment: @Moo Yes, these are the discussions I was looking for. Thank you. However, all these determine the direction by looking at b (or c), but not the difference. I still don't know how b-c comes in the picture that is claimed on the resource I linked. Probably these conditions are equivalent for complex eigenvalues, I need to think about it.

Comment: In fact, I just understood that it was equivalent to consider the sign of $b-c$ and/or the sign of $-c$  (minus $c$) being assumed that $(a-d)^2+4bc<0$ (ensuring complex eigenvalues). If I have time, I will explain why.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I can also see the equivalence now (following your hint about the discriminant). I was still curious about the b-c and found the following. If we look at the vector field (ax+by,cx+dy,0), then the curl of this vector field is (0,0,c-b). This may explain why the sign of b-c was mentioned and not the sign of c or b.

Comment: Hint. 

Consider the system

$$
\left(\matrix{\dot x\\ \dot y}\right)=\left(\matrix{a + i b & 0\\ 0 & a - i b}\right)\left(\matrix{ x\\  y}\right)
$$

with solution

$$
\cases{
x = x_0 e^{a t}e^{i b t}\\
y = y_0 e^{a t}e^{-i b t}
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Wew can diagonalize the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix} m_1 & 0 \\ 0 & m_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then we work with $(X,Y)$ instead of $(x,y)$. Yhe eigenvalues are gicven by $$m_1,m_2=\frac{1}{2}[(a+d)\pm \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc}]$$ Suppose

Case (1): $m_1=1, m_2=2 \implies X=e^t, Y=e^{2t}\implies Y=X^2,$ we get parabolic trajectory.
Next, suppose

Case(2):$m=-1, m_2=-2 \implies X=e^{-t}, Y=e^{-2t}$, we again get get parabolic trajectory $Y=X^2$.

But the difference is that when time increases to $\infty$ in case (1) both $X,Y$ diverge away from origin (0,0). So the arrow goes out and the orbit is unstable. In case (2) the arrow will direct towards origin, orbit will be stable.

When eigenvalues are non-real (Complex) we get spiral trajectories if $\Re (m_1,m_2)>0$, $X,Y$ diverge, we get unstable spiral. Otherwise, we get stable spiral.

One may call unstable spiral as clockwise and stable one as anti-clockwise.

Any way the sign of real part of eigenvalues decides this.

When eigenvalues are real but of opposite sign the origin becomes a saddle point.

You find a good discussion on this in Problems in ODE by M.L. Krasnov et al (MIR Publication)

Comment: I am indeed interested in the case when the trajectory is a spiral, but I do not think that clockwise/anticlockwise is the same as unstable/stable. A stable trajectory can spiral towards the origin two different ways, clockwise or anticlockwise. Similarly an unstable spiral can also move clockwise and anticlockwise.

Comment: @Ferenc Beleznay I fully agree with you...

Comment: @Ferenc BeleznayThen how to prove clockwise and anticlocwise trajectories  with regards to b+c?

Comment: @ZAhmed This is what I am interested in. My approach was to try x=0 y=1 and look at the direction of the tangent. If it points towards the first quadrant, then it is clockwise, if it points towards the second quadrant, then it is anticlockwise. But this give the condition b>0 or b<0. I do not know how b-c comes in the picture.

Comment: @Z Ahmed Not $b+c$ but $b-c$.